# Package QCA: truthTable logical remainders not printing despite complete = TRUE

Tags: r

I am using the QCA and SetMethods packages for R to conduct a QCA.
I have created a truth table with my data, using the function `truthTable` including the argument `complete = TRUE` to print the logical remainders.
The data has 11 conditions, the tt should then have 2048 rows, but when I call the truth table object, only the 22 rows with observed cases are printed.

Here is the code used to construct the truthTable. The file qca_selec can be uploaded from [here](https://dropit.uni.lu/invitations?share=3226eede0ed3d1676557).

```
# Data set 'qca_selec':
qca_selec <- readRDS("qca_selec.RDS")

# Vector of condition names:
cond <- c("COALSIZE" "FINAMOOD" "COALEXPE" "COALCOOR" "PUBLSUPP" "NFBUSUPP" "WEAKOPPO" "ISSUSALI" "ISSUCOMP" "ISSUNOVE" "ISSUPOLI")

# Truth table:
tt <- truthTable(data = qca_selec, outcome = "~SUCCESS", conditions = cond,
                            incl.cut = 0.75, pri.cut = 0.51, n.cut = 2, sort.by = "incl", 
                            show.cases = TRUE, complete = TRUE)
tt
```

I used the same code for other truth tables with up to 7 conditions and it worked fine, showed me all the rows, including remainders. Is there anything particular to add when using the function with more than 7 conditions? I could not find anything in the QCA package documentation.

I should also note that when using functions from the SetMethods package (the `esa` and `LR.intersect`functions, to be precise), on solutions based on this particular truth table, I also experienced issues.
Basically, the `LR.intersect`function is unable to identify the specified models (there is model ambiguity); and the `esa` function seems not to change the values of the `contrad_rows` and `nec_cond`(well, I can't actually check the changes in the tt since it does not print the LRs, but the resulting ESA solutions are exactly the same as the SA solutions, so I guess that it does not change anything).

Has anyone be confronted to a similar issue before?

I'm using

- R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01); Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit); Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.5
- SetMethods_3.0 and QCA_3.14
- I also have the tidyverse packages loaded, could that create any conflict with a long tt?

I would be immensely grateful for any help from the community!

Comment: You didn't include `qca_selec`, so I can't reproduce the error. I took a look at the `truthTable` function, between what it uses and `dplyr`, there are several potential sources of the problems you have. However, I didn't find any issues with the functions `lag` or `filter`-- where `dplyr` conflicts with the base package `stat`. (I didn't look through everything, though.) If you call `tidyverse` **first**, then your other libraries, you shouldn't have a problem. Alternatively, make your question reproducible: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added a link to the data set `qca_selec`. I actually already call `tidyverse` first and only then `QCA` and `SetMethods` because I had already noticed conflicts between functions...

Comment: Remove `conditions = cond` If you look in the environment pane, you won't find the object `cond`. That line of code doesn't work without commas. You don't have to fix that though. `truthTable()` infers the conditions based on the data structure.

Comment: Thanks, @Kat. I removed the `conditions = cond` argument but the truth table still prints without the logical remainders. Does it work on your side?